# Using sound in pygame is crashing my game

Tags: audio, pygame, crash

I'm trying to make a "clicking" sound for when the user presses a button, but pygame is crashing when I try to use it

The error I get is:

Fatal Python error: PyEval_SaveThread: NULL tstate

Current thread 0x00007f8c1acf2740 (most recent call first):
File "/home/lucas1809/\xc1rea de Trabalho/Projetos/sudokey/main.py", line 60 in module

```
click = pygame.mixer.Sound("sons/click.ogg") #I first create the click instance
```

```
pygame.mixer.Sound.play(click, 1) #Then, I play it on the main loop
```

I already tried to change the frequency of the mixer to 44100, as suggested in another post, but the problem remains

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it work when the script and the .ogg file are in the same path?

Comment: sorry for the answer delay, but, no. It's the same

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that's the way to play a sound file in pygame.

In my experience this is how a sound file is played,

```
    sound=pygame.mixer.Sound(file2)
    sound.play(loops=0)
```

The default value (zero) means the Sound is not repeated, and so is only played once. If loops is set to -1 the Sound will loop indefinitely (though you can still call stop() to stop it).

Else you can do

```
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(pygame.mixer.Sound('Cutting_Rope.wav'))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: tried, didn't work :/  However, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Ivalencia - Everything Afijaabb presents above is correct.  Maybe you need to add more code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the `play()` incorrectly.  Referring to the [manual](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.play), `play()` does not take the sound-object as an argument.  I guess the code is mixing up the loading of the sound, and the playing of it.

The loading function `pygame.mixer.Sound()` loads the sound file, returning a sound object.  To play the sound object, you need to call `.play()` on the sound object itself.  Whereas your code is trying to use sound loader function again.

You probably want something like:

```
### initialisation
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

click = pygame.mixer.Sound( "sons/click.ogg" ) # I first create the click instance

click.play() # play the sound
```

Looking at the way your code is written, perhaps you may have intended to use PyGame sound *mixer channels*. This does use a similar call-layout to the code  in the question.

```
### initialisation
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

# create separate Channel objects for simultaneous playback
channel1 = pygame.mixer.Channel(0) # argument must be int
channel2 = pygame.mixer.Channel(1)

# Load the sound
click = pygame.mixer.Sound( "sons/click.ogg" ) # I first create the click instance

# Play the sound
channel1.play( click )
```

Using mixer channels allows you to play multiple sounds simultaneously, it's quite a handy way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, It didn't work. The error is the same. Also tried to use Channels, but failed too